# How can I secure my code in an Apache Tomcat Server?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, rest, tomcat

So I'm developing a project for a client and in the end they will have a server running Apache Tomcat Server 7.0 and my project .war will be deployed there. Basically the .war will be running on their server and they will have access to it.

Can anyone provide any tips in how can i secure my code and prevent them to give it a look?  Because the logic of the program itself it's what makes it valuable *per se*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to send source code up in a WAR file. But the resulting java binaries will still be subject to reverse engineering and decompilation, if they're so inclined. You'd need to look in to java obfuscation to try and manage that.

You can even use JSPs for presentation, but you'll want to pre-compile those in to servlets before distribution.

Do not disregard legal mechanisms through licensing of your work. Make sure your licenses and contracts are very clear about code ownership and rights to the software. That's a place for a lawyer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Will. I guess I'm going to work with java obfuscators then. Can you explain better your second paragraph or provide some links (sorry for the trouble)? I call my question solved guys, I just don't have enough rep to vote you Will. Thanks again.